# How to open different Gallery for each image using fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, image-gallery

I'm using fancybox-2.1.5 and I can use it as normal usage like `$('.fancybox').fancybox();`

but now I need to open different gallery for each click on image tag

for example:

`<a href='#'><img src='photo-a.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery'/></a>
<a href='#'><img src='photo-b.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery'/></a>
<a href='#'><img src='photo-c.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery'/></a>`

when `photo-a.jpg` clicked.must open gallery for `photo-1.jpg,photo-2.jpg and photo-3.jpg`

when `photo-b.jpg` clicked.must open gallery for `photo-4.jpg,photo-5.jpg and photo-6.jpg`... etc

How to make this using fancybox and ajax if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign different rel for different gallery.

```
<a href='#'><img src='photo-a.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1'/></a>
            <img src='photo-a1.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1'/>
            <img src='photo-a2.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery1'/>
<a href='#'><img src='photo-b.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery2'/></a>
           <img src='photo-b1.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery2'/>
           <img src='photo-b3.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery2'/>
<a href='#'><img src='photo-c.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery3'/></a>
            <img src='photo-c1.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery3'/>
            <img src='photo-c2.jpg' class='fancybox' rel='gallery3'/>
```

just like that.

Note: always read documentation before apply

Comment: Bear in mind the code above will open the thumbnail (`<img>` tag) in fancybox and will set a `style="display:none"` attribute to that tag after placing it back in the document flow. The *class* fancybox should be placed in the `<a>` tag in normal conditions. Always read the documentation before apply ;)